# How th allow two threads execute in a predefined order in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i have more than one handler (thread) execute , and some thread depends on the result of other one .. so i want to make threads execute in a defined order

Comment: If you need to perform the processing consecutively, why do you need more than one thread?  You can't directly control order of thread execution, so the second thread is going to have to be put into a block state to wait for some event triggered by the first.  Is this feasible, or is the second thread doing other stuff in which case you're going to end up polling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start the second thread from the first thread.

```
final Thread th2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        doSomething2;
    }
}
Thread th1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        doSomething;
        th2.start();
    }
});
th1.start();
th2.join();
```

But you most probably don't need the second thread at all:

```
Thread th1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        doSomething;
        doSomething2;
    }
});
th1.start();
th1.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to wait in one thread for another thread to complete, there are several options.

One is to use a CountdownLatch,

Somewhere common share the latch
    CountdownLatch latch = new CountdownLatch(1);

Thread 1,

```
 doSomething();
 countdownLatch.countdown();
```

Thread 2,

```
 countdownLatch.await();
 doSomethingElse();
```

Countdown latches can only be used once though.

There are a bunch of other classes in [java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) that may solve your problem.  LinkedBlockingQueue, CyclicBarrier, Exchanger may be useful.  Its hard to say more without knowing more details.

And as the comment and other answer pointed out, if you can, just avoid multiple threads altogether.